# Ubuntu desktop slows down

Tags: gnome, ram

At once I will say that I am new to using linux. I use Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. And I had a problem with the desktop. The desktop sometimes slows down and folders do not always drag to another location and freezing. What could be the problem?

For @Marmayogi request

```
free --giga
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:              8           1           5           0           1           5
Swap:             2           0           2
```

```
sudo lshw -short -class memory
H/W path       Device     Class          Description
====================================================
/0/0                      memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/8                      memory         8GiB System Memory
/0/8/0                    memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0,
/0/8/1                    memory         [empty]
/0/8/2                    memory         [empty]
/0/8/3                    memory         [empty]
/0/e                      memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/f                      memory         512KiB L2 cache
/0/10                     memory         4MiB L3 cache
/0/100/1f.2               memory         Memory controller
```

For @heynnema request

```
ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 zuodion zuodion 4096 apr  6 10:25 .
drwx------ 3 zuodion zuodion 4096 apr  6 19:10 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 zuodion zuodion 4096 apr  6 10:25 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92109/discussion-on-question-by-zuodion-ubuntu-desktop-problem).

Comment: @zuodion are you opening up and using multiple applications on your ubuntu system concurrently? What about your browser activities? Are you a heavy internet surfer? Are you often keeping up multiple web pages  on your browser concurrently?

Comment: @Marmayogi This problem occurs even if applications or browsers are not running.

Comment: @zuodion you have a 2 GB swap already. You can have multiple swap files under Ubuntu. Why don't you create an additional 4 GB swap file and verify the problem is solved or not. Later, it is found that this does not yield desired results, then you can always delete it! No harm done! To create a swap file, refer [How to create a SWAP file](https://www.fosslinux.com/1064/how-to-create-or-add-a-swap-partition-in-ubuntu-and-linux-mint.htm). Please give a try!

Comment: @zuodion I just got caught up with the chat... and it sounds like 18.10 worked for you, yes?

Comment: @Marmayogi 8G RAM w/2G swap. Why would you think that more swap would help? There's no data to support that.

Comment: @heynnema yeah, but can i just upgrade to 18.10 without losing system preferences, data and other stuff?

Comment: @zuodion yes, just use Software Updater. Of course, it's always good to have a backup, just in case :-) 18.10 working from a USB flash key is not a 100% assurance that it'll fix your problem, but it costs nothing to try to upgrade. It might be good to do a fsck on your Ubuntu partition first... do you know how to do that, or should I update my answer and give you instructions?

Comment: @heynnema If it's not hard for you, can you give me instructions?

Comment: @zuodion sure! Give me just a minute or two...

Comment: @zuodion Done! Keep me posted.

Comment: @heynnema, the idea of going for 4GB swap file is for testing only. If this solution does not work, then you may drop this file altogether. Whereas if it works, then you can always reduce and adjust this swap file to correct value. Not a problem.  We are all trying to solve questioner's  problem. Hope you get my point.

Comment: @Marmayogi documenting how to create more swap, or a /swapfile, obtaining new UUID's (for swap partitions), and how to modify /etc/fstab could get a user into a lot more trouble. And swap won't effect the desktop problem as described anyway.

Comment: We are talking about swap file @heynnema. You don't need for any UUID stuff here. The  command to execute is: `echo '/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab`. Very simple.

Comment: @Marmayogi as I mentioned, the UUID's are only (for swap **partitions**). You also didn't articulate the **commands** required to create the /swapfile. No matter, 'cause we're on a different path right now anyway :-)

Comment: @heynnema, please refer my comments. I always mentioned and articulated  very clearly that is it **swap file** not **swap partition**.  I can't  produce entire procedure at the command level in a comment section regarding **How to create a swap file**.

Comment: @Marmayogi not to belabor the point... but did you consider what if the user already had a /swapfile, /etc/fstab would already have the /swapfile line in it, then executing your echo/tee commands would cause a problem, as now there would be **two** lines in /etc/fstab. It's not all quite as easy as you think. Enough about this subject.

Comment: It is very simple. Call first file as `swapfile1` and call second file as `swapfile2` and so on. This is how Ubuntu supports multiple swap files! So there is no clash at /etc/fstab level.

Comment: @heynnema Ubuntu update did not help. But I think I know what the problem is. The problem is probably in HDD. The desktop is in HDD and I noticed that the video that is on the HDD also sometimes lags. But the video that is on SSD has no such problems. So can I fix that or just move /home from HDD to SSD?

Comment: @zuodion Too bad. Start the `Disks` app, select your HDD, then go to the "hamburger" icon, and select `SMART Data & Tests`. Review the data, pay attention to items that include the word "sector". Then run the tests. Report back. Also, lets check syslog for disk errors... `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*`. Copy/paste that output into imgur.com if they're lengthy.

Comment: @heynnema yeah, there are many errors and 1230 damaged sectors. So I think, I need to move /home to SSD. And use the HDD only as storage.

Comment: @zuodion Show me screenshots of the SMART Data, and put the syslog errors on imgur.com... let me look at them... and AFTER I've looked at the info... we'll probably end up doing **Update #3** in my answer... but wait for me...

Comment: @heynnema Here screenshot from SMART Data https://imgur.com/a/5EZiei9 . But how can i give to you log file?

Comment: @zuodion I'll go look at the screenshots. To let me see the syslog, do the grep command, select all the text, copy it to the clipboard, go to imgur.com (or paste.ubuntu.com), paste the raw text, give me the link.

Comment: Here a logs https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9bMb4WFNsb/

Comment: @zuodion OK, the SMART Data shows 1232 pending sectors, that's the important one. The syslog didn't show any sda errors. Let's try that again. Boot to the HDD and do `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` (note the ending *) (and I'm assuming that your HDD is sda... but if it's not, then change to sdb, or whatever).

Comment: I switched to SSD on my old laptop that used to freeze all the time using a HDD and now it doesn't.

Comment: @zuodion status please... where did you go?

Comment: @heynnema Sorry it was already 1am. So here the logs from `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VYSVS6XxMs/

Comment: @zuodion I looked at syslog. I'm a little surprised that I don't see any sda errors. There are a LOT of font errors, and they should be resolved. It looks like sda is finding marginal/bad sectors on a read, but not marking them as bad cause it's waiting for a write. So every time it hits 1232 of them, it could cause a slowdown (in your desktop). Backup your important Ubuntu files, and go ahead and do my **Update #3** using my recommended command. Report back.

Comment: @zuodion the SMART "Current Pending Sector Count" should be something less than 1232, or maybe even 0, after bad blocking sda.

Comment: @zuodion status please...

Comment: @heynnema I entered the command `sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sda1` and according to my calculations, this check will last about 15 hours, and I need a laptop for work, so I will put up for the night and write back tomorrow night.

Comment: @zuodion fair enough. It's not a great idea to stop a bad block scan once it's started... so, when you restart it again, let it run all the way through to the end, ok?

Comment: @heynnema ok, I got you

Comment: @heynnema So after bad block scan i got selftest failed and now my computer doesnt boot, it's just loading screen.

Comment: @zuodion are you talking about SMART or disk selftest? Did the bad block check complete this time? Did it give any summary information? Describe exactly what you see on the screen. If you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, can you see the contents of the hard drive?

Comment: @zuodion After you boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, start `Disks` and look at the SMART Data and tell me what the "Current Pending Sector Count" is, and then run the SMART tests. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Current pending sector count is 1232. Also i cant have done the selftest cause its freezed on 10%. Also the value of Read error Rate is 225312793. I think the HDD is dead...

Comment: Yes, maybe so. Certainly explains what you were seeing. After booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, can you see the contents of the HDD? Do/did you have Wndows on this HDD?

Comment: @heynnema, no there is nothing

Comment: @zuodion too bad, but not a real surprise. Good news is that HDD's are really cheap now. SSD's have also come way down too. Have you decided what you are going to do?

Comment: @zuodion How big is your SSD? Did you have Windows installed? If so, on SSD or HDD?

Comment: @heynnema SSD have 240Gb, for my work its fair enough. Thank you for help. I have installed window in other computer.

Comment: @zuodion I did a mini-update on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete these tasks...

- select "Ubuntu" environment at the login screen cogwheel
- upgrade the BIOS to 313/314 https://www.asus.com/ph/Laptops/ASUS-Vivobook-X556UQ/HelpDesk_BIOS/
- run `memtest` from a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB (complete 4/4 passes, if you have the time)
- disable the discrete video card, as it's broken (disable the driver, or in the BIOS)
- disable wayland, like so...

---

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /      # to remount the disk r/w

sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.

**Update #1:**

We booted to a Ubuntu Live 18.10 USB, and no problems were seen.

**Update #2:**

Before upgrading to 18.10, to see if that fixes the problem with the desktop, we should do a `fsck` first to check your file system, then you can use `Software Updater` to do the upgrade. Of course... having a good backup never hurts... just in case something goes wrong :-)

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #3:**

To eliminate the possibility of bad blocks on your HDD causing your problem, we'll test to find any bad blocks.

First, start the `Disks` app, select your HDD, then go to the "hamburger" icon, and select `SMART Data & Tests`. Review the data, pay attention to items that include the word "sector". Then run the tests.

Also, lets check syslog for disk errors... `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*`. Copy/paste that output into imgur.com (or paste.ubuntu.com) if they're lengthy.

**Note**: It's always a good idea to have backup of your important Ubuntu files.

So do this to test for bad blocks... (this may take a while)...

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Open `terminal`...

Use the fdisk method from **Update #2** to figure out `/dev/sdaX`.

`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdaX` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdaX` # non-destructive read/write test (**recommended**)

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f     Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c     This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
          read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
          If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
          inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
          tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
          scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k     When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
          bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
          running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
          list.

   -y     Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
          used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
          same time as the -n or -p options.
```

**Update #4:**

During/after the bad block scan, the drive died. Will require replacement.

Answer (score 0):

If that problem occurs in a virtual machine, I had a similar problem. In vmbox, the problem can be resolved by changing the number of processors to 2 (or more depending on your system) from Settings>System>Processors.

Comment: I use Ubuntu as main OS without VM